# Alterar topo de uma página só do cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Peguei um site para fazer manutenção e ele está em `CakePHP` (framework que não trabalho). Ele faz algumas rotas para todos os arquivos que estão dentro da pasta `view/pages`

**routes.php**

```
foreach(scandir('../View/Pages') as $path){
        if (is_dir('../View/Pages/' . $path)) {
            foreach(scandir('../View/Pages/' . $path) as $subPath){
                if(pathinfo($subPath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "ctp"){
                    $name = pathinfo($subPath, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                    Router::connect('/' . $path . '/' .$name, array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', $path . '/' . $name));
                }
            }
        } else {
            if(pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "ctp"){
                $name = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                Router::connect('/'.$name, array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', $name));
            }
        }
    }
```

A página fica acessível normalmente, mas mandaram uma alteração pra eu fazer aonde o logo de uma página **(upcreditos.ctp)** será diferente das demais páginas. O problema começa porque o site coloca o mesmo topo, navbar e rodapé para as páginas e só muda mesmo o meio. Como eu não sei como funciona o `CakePHP` então não sei como criar um `header.ctp` personalizado e só colocar pra executar na página **upcreditos.ctp**. Colocarei o controller **pages** abaixo para vocês visualizarem como está:

**PagesController.php**

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class PagesController extends AppController {

    public $uses = array();

    public function display() {
        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

        try {
            $this->render(implode('/', $path));
        } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                throw $e;
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }

    public function admin_display() {
        $path = func_get_args();

        $count = count($path);
        if (!$count) {
            return $this->redirect('/');
        }
        $page = $subpage = $title_for_layout = null;

        if (!empty($path[0])) {
            $page = $path[0];
        }
        if (!empty($path[1])) {
            $subpage = $path[1];
        }
        if (!empty($path[$count - 1])) {
            $title_for_layout = Inflector::humanize($path[$count - 1]);
        }
        $this->set(compact('page', 'subpage', 'title_for_layout'));

        try {
            $this->render(implode('/', $path));
        } catch (MissingViewException $e) {
            if (Configure::read('debug')) {
                throw $e;
            }
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }
    }
}
```

Preciso de uma luz para saber como alterar só o topo. Se precisarem que eu poste algum controller, model ou view aqui é só pedir, pois não sei o que precisa para resolver essa alteração.

Answer (score 1):

Não lembro muito bem, faz tempo que não trabalho com CakePHP, mas uma das soluções possíveis é trabalhar com múltiplos [layouts](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/views.html#layouts).

Para a view específica, você pode setar um layout diferente para ela no controller e adaptá-la:

```
// de um controller
public function view() {
    // códigos
    $this->layout = 'admin';
}
```

Ou da view:

```
// de um arquivo view
$this->layout = 'loggedin';
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu criaria elements das partes iguais visando a reutilização e criaria dois layouts ou até mesmo se for somente uma pagina usaria:
`$this->layout = false;` e colocaria tudo na view mas usando os elements mesmo assim.